# Problems with [contenteditable] elements and jQuery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate, contenteditable

I prepared a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/z6eLvk0b/1/)** which demonstrates `[contenteditable]` element has no HTML form. As for me, it's a problem, because jQuery validation plugin need form. Look at the source code snippet [from here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js#L383) starting from 383 line:

```
function delegate( event ) {
    var validator = $.data( this.form, "validator" ),
        eventType = "on" + event.type.replace( /^validate/, "" ),
        settings = validator.settings;
    if ( settings[ eventType ] && !$( this ).is( settings.ignore ) ) {
        settings[ eventType ].call( validator, this, event );
    }
}

$( this.currentForm )
    .on( "focusin.validate focusout.validate keyup.validate",
        ":text, [type='password'], [type='file'], select, textarea, [type='number'], [type='search'], " +
        "[type='tel'], [type='url'], [type='email'], [type='datetime'], [type='date'], [type='month'], " +
        "[type='week'], [type='time'], [type='datetime-local'], [type='range'], [type='color'], " +
        "[type='radio'], [type='checkbox'], [contenteditable]", delegate )

    // Support: Chrome, oldIE
    // "select" is provided as event.target when clicking a option
    .on( "click.validate", "select, option, [type='radio'], [type='checkbox']", delegate );
```

Here we can see, elements, one of which is a `[contenteditable]` listen to events and then call `delegate` event handler.

When `[contenteditable]` trigger some event from this list, `delegate` method try to get validator from element `var validator = $.data( this.form, "validator" )` but as I said earlier `[contenteditable]` has no form (see **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/z6eLvk0b/1/)**).

Is there any way to solve this problem? May be it's possible to add form to all `[contenteditable]` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in `jquery validator plugin`. However, this has been fixed now in this [pull request](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/pull/1785), and should be released soon.

## Fix 1:

If you cannot wait for a release, the fix is to put this code at the start of `delegate()` method. The solution has been made by `@svrx`.

```
// Set form expando on contenteditable
if ( !this.form && this.hasAttribute( "contenteditable" ) ) {
    this.form = $( this ).closest( "form" )[ 0 ];
}
```

As you can see the fix is simply to set the form to the parent element.

## Fix 2:

As `@chrisAtomix` said in his [comments](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1729), don't use the latest `jquery validator plugin`. Instead use a lower version where `contenteditable` feature has not been added. He is using `v1.14.0`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I use `v1.14.0` and wait for a release

Answer (score 0):

does exploring the ignore option of validate solve your problem?

```
ignore: ":hidden:not('#summernote')"
```

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z6eLvk0b/2/