# Contenteditable not working with JQuery Validate?

Tags: jquery, validation, contenteditable

I have this line of code.

```
'<div contenteditable="true" class="test">heredasdsa</div>'
```

Whenever I click on it and try to edit it I am prompted with the following error

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery2240134174842298528722' of undefined
at M.get (jquery.min.js:2)
at M.access (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.data (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.b (application.js:8317)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

When I go to the specific line of code where the issue lies, it takes me to jquery.min.js and specifically highlights the code block below as the error.

```
return void 0 === b ? this.cache(a) : a[this.expando] && a[this.expando][b]
```

I have no idea how to fix this at all. 
*Sorry If I'm not posting correctly, this is my first time posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: I believe this question is not related to ruby and ruby-on-rails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with \[contenteditable\] elements and jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383647/problems-with-contenteditable-elements-and-jquery-validation-plugin)

Comment: Thanks. I've flagged it as a duplicate (not that it's a bad question, but if one already exists cleaning up is good)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a known bug with the Jquery Validate Plugin. Simply updated to latest version.

Comment: Not a whole lot of changes in the validation plugin since 2017. This is what I needed though.